# DOM parsing works in one Activity, but not in another with the same code?

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, dom

I don't get it.

I have two activities in which i parse an XML-file dat is located in the private data directory of my app.

I use this method to parse my XML file:

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir() + "/autopech.xml");
        if (file.exists() == true) {
            DocumentBuilder builder2 = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc2 = builder2.parse(new FileInputStream(file));
            NodeList nl2 = doc2.getElementsByTagName("verzekeraar");
            for (int i = 0; i < nl2.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node = nl2.item(i);
                Bank bnk = new Bank();
                bnk.setNaam(Xml.innerHtml(Xml.getChildByTagName(node, "naam")));
                bnk.setTel(Xml.innerHtml(Xml.getChildByTagName(node, "tel")));

                lijst.add(bnk);
            }
        }
```

This method works in 1 activity, but throws me an `02-03 14:18:10.047: WARN/System.err(8221): org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected end of document`
at this line: `Document doc2 = builder2.parse(new FileInputStream(file));`

I really don't get it. It's EXACT the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because i used the parsing in another method. I seperated the process in it's own method and it worked.